# Wordpress Install in subdirectory, login gives away the directory name

Tags: wordpress, installation, duplicates, subdirectory

I wanted to have my next wordpress package running in a subdirectory for two reasons.

- it's cleaner
- it's supposed to add a level of safety to my install

(http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

The Wordpress Codex is very helpfull on this topic and I got it running on the first try but I still have some questions:

1. As the login now uses the subdirectory for the url, the login link gives away where wordpress is installed. I didn't plan to use a frontend login solution for this install.
2. Is it correct that this wont cause any duplicate content issues as long as I don't use the subdirectory name in any links? All pages seem to be accessible with both urls now. (mysite.net/ and mysite.net/subdir/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think having WordPress in a subdirectory is safer?

Comment: the keyword to pursue here is `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` file I think.

Comment: @Blender I think that was a misconception on my side. The article I remembered was about a wordpress install with no login visible/accessible on the site. The "safety" was that to login and hack your admin account, the attacker would have to first guess the subdirectory for the login. As that is not the case for me, I won't gain any safety besides the clean root dir. My admin login isn't admin by the way. ^^